# Adding a 2nd Router to Improve Wireless Access Thru out my house

Tags: router

"Any old router will do".....????

I only see  Internet advice saying "any old router will do"....

Wouldn't I get best performance if I bought another router that matches the performance specs of my main router upstairs in my house ?

My main router is an Asus AC 3200 Triband router giving me excellent wireless performance upstairs...

But downstairs my signal gets flaky....

If I buy a brandy new Asus AC 3200 Triband router for downstairs and setting it up as an access point....

e.g.  Another AC 3200 Triband router will give me BEST wireless network performance ?
I cannot find any article on the Internet that can deal with or answer this question.

Will you agree that my question has merit ?
Can you confirm my suspicion that a router at least equal to the main router will yield best performance ?

Many thanks for taking my question,
Mike Higgins

Answer (score 0):

I keep my main and wireless routers closely matched. The wireless router should have similar throughput to the main router. If you have good ISP speed and good wireless capability in your device, then "any old router" may not give you good performance. I get the same throughput on both my routers.

Also, if transferring large files between devices, you will want equal throughput.

Yes, your question has merit for people looking in.

Comment: After moving my main router and adjusting the antenna to focus the signal down the stair case, I used my phone's signal meter to trace the signal throughout my house.  At the bottom of the stairs, the signal strength is strong turning to the right.... into my living room.  I want the signal strength to turn left into my den where all my devices are.   The signal degrades to fair or poor turning to the left into the den.  I even removed the door at the bottom of the stairs...    Any ideas how I can "shape" or "bend" the sigal to the left ?

Comment: It depends on the physical characteristics of the router. An available router may be OK or not, but I like to keep weak links to a minimum to avoid issues.

Comment: I took some time to consider my own setup because I added a Ubiquiti Access Point. The signal radiation is roughly a circle and the radiation can penetrate some things and not others. But largely, I do not think you can bend signals. That is not likely to work.

Comment: @John That's not strictly true as radio signals can be reflected. That's how radio telescopes with a parabolic dish reflect all the waves to the receiver at the end of the spike.

Comment: I understand that but user (consumer) equipment tends to be a bit simpler and the consistently varies by the kind and quality of equipment.

Comment: I resolved my wireless access downstairs by complementing my main Asus AC3200 router with another Asus router AC1900 setting it up as an access point with a wired connection back to the main router.  I;ve had excellent results from this setup with the added benefit of also extending my wireless access reach to my driveway and front yard....  this give me access to my wifi as I sit in my car before leaving and arriving home.